# htaccess with UTF-8

Tags: php, .htaccess

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /WWWv2.0/mvc/public
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

the above code is not returned Polish characters,
for example, wwwv2.0/mvc/public/ąćłęabc  only returns  abc

Comment: What is the full URL you're entering in browser?

Comment: http://localhost/wwwv2.0/mvc/public/aęąćłębc

Comment: Does it return 404 to you?

Comment: no i get normal array Array ( [0] => abc

Answer (score 0):

i found problem

```
if(isset($_GET['url']))
        {
            return $url = explode('/', filter_var( rtrim($_GET['url'],"/") , FILTER_SANITIZE_URL ));
        }
```

filter_var($var, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL) is removes special characters